# Not able to create conda environment MacOS

Tags: python, macos, anaconda, conda

I'm currently struggling with setting up an conda environment on my macOS Big Sur.
I have no clue how to fix it. Google couldn't help me...

The problem:

- python 3.9.4 is installed
- newest anaconda version is installed
- % conda create -n markenv python=3.9.4 anaconda

occurs the following error line:

```
base) macmarkus@Markuss-MacBook-Pro ~ % conda create -n markenv python=3.9.4 anaconda  Collecting package metadata (current_repodata.json): done Solving environment: failed with repodata from current_repodata.json, will retry with next repodata source. Collecting package metadata (repodata.json): done Solving environment: |  Found conflicts! Looking for incompatible packages. This can take several minutes.  Press CTRL-C to abort. failed         


UnsatisfiableError: The following specifications were found to be incompatible with each other:

Output in format: Requested package -> Available versions

Package python conflicts for: anaconda -> python[version='2.7.13|2.7.14|2.7.14|2.7.15|2.7.15|2.7.16|2.7.16|3.6.10|3.6.10|3.7.7|3.7.9|3.8.5|3.8.3|3.8.1|3.7.6|3.6.9|3.7.4|3.6.8|3.7.3|3.6.7|3.7.1|3.7.0|3.6.6|3.6.5|3.5.5|3.6.4|3.5.4|3.6.3|3.5.4|3.6.2|3.5.4|>=3.8,<3.9.0a0|>=3.7,<3.8.0a0|>=2.7,<2.8.0a0|>=3.6,<3.7.0a0|>=3.5,<3.6.0a0',build='h26d10c0_12|he768d2d_19|hb8880cc_19|hde5916a_29|h0a44026_3|hc167b69_0|h138c1fe_0|h8f8e585_6|h359304d_0|h97142e2_0|haf84260_0|h359304d_0|h359304d_0|hf48f09d_4|h26836e1_0|h26836e1_1|hf48f09d_2|h26836e1_2|h359304d_1|h359304d_2|h97142e2_7|h359304d_1|haf84260_0|haf84260_7|hc167b69_0|hc167b69_1|hc167b69_1|he720263_23|h6804ab2_0|h32f5f24_13|he1de2d4_12'] python=3.9.4 anaconda -> alabaster==0.7.12=py_0 -> python[version='2.7.*|3.5.*|3.6.*|<4.0|>2.7|>=3.6|>=3.5|>=3|>=3.6,<4.0|>=3.4|>=3.7|>=3,<3.7|3.8.*|3.7.*']
```

Hopefully someone can help me with fixing that!
Thanks a lot :) (its zsh)

[image]

Comment: Anaconda does not support Python 3.9 yet: [Managing Python](https://docs.conda.io/projects/conda/en/latest/user-guide/tasks/manage-python.html)

Comment: Do you have to have `anaconda` in the environment? For most users that is rarely the case. Try just `conda create -n markenv python=3.9.4`